# Move a trill into the stave

Tags: lilypond, songwriting

In lilypond, I'd like to draw a zig-zagged line after a note which lasts until the next note.

Basically, I'd like to create something which looks like this:

[image: Rhythm looks something like: ||-C-x~~~~~x-x-- where '~' represents trill line]
<sup>(sorry for the poor quality)</sup>

## UPDATE

I have managed to remove the 'tr' text and now have achieved this:

[image]

```
\new DrumStaff \with {
  instrumentName = #"Güiro "
  shortInstrumentName = #"Guir. "
}
{
  \stopStaff
  \override Staff.StaffSymbol.line-count = #1
  \startStaff
  \override NoteHead.style = #'cross
  \override TrillSpanner bound-details.left.text = ##f
  r4 c4\startTrillSpan e8\stopTrillSpan c8 c4 |
}
```

but how can I get the zig-zag line to be on the same staff-line that the note head is?

Comment: I know very little about LilyPond's builtin symbols, but perhaps a repeated upper mordent mark?

Comment: Your images show up blank with "no access" symbols for me.  Could you upload them to imgur?  (The editing/compose interface here will let you do that easily.)

Comment: @MatthewRead If I upload them to imgur, then I can't see them. My place of work filters imgur.

Comment: What musical purpose are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: @jjmusicnotes On the güiro I am trying to represent a 'scrape' (not sure how to describe it; when the beater is stroked down the textured part of the instrument)

Comment: @theonlygusti You don't need special notation for that, it's just how the instrument is played. If you want to emphasize it, you could put a tenuto marking I suppose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try a glissando with either the `zigzag` (a thin line) or `trill` style (bolder); however, this requires *not* using `DrumStaff` (or to enable the by-default disabled glissando engraver on a `DrumStaff`, but that produced poor results in testing), and may require a manual `right Y` setting, as otherwise the glissando chases the next note. However, that need is obviated by the use of a single rhythmic line, as every note is on staff line `0`. A glissando is more suitable as it is a "within staff" object (see the [learning manual](http://lilypond.org/manuals.html)), while a trill spanner is an "outside staff" object so thus probably tricker to move between notes. Ties and slurs are bendy, and `laissezVibrer` appears to lack a `trill` style; I could produce nothing as suitable as from a glissando while experimenting.

Horizontal spacing will be a concern, as by default the trill line is very short between notes. There *may* be issues if the glissando runs into a line break, as there's some special code for `after-line-breaking`, but I don't know how to write a test case that would exercise that.

```
\version "2.18.2"

\score {
  \new RhythmicStaff \with {
    \consists "Clef_engraver"
    instrumentName = #"Güiro "
    shortInstrumentName = #"Guir. "
  } {
    \clef percussion

    \override Glissando #'style = #'trill
    % if multiple staff lines KLUGE must adjust this manually
    % but we're on a single staff line so probably do not need
    \override Glissando #'(bound-details right Y) = #0

    \override NoteHead #'style = #'cross

    % stretch things out (probably will need tweaks)
    \override Score.SpacingSpanner #'strict-note-spacing = ##t
    \set Score.proportionalNotationDuration = #(ly:make-moment 1 16)

    \stemDown
    r4 c4\glissando c8[ c] c4
  }
  \layout { }
}
```

This was figured out by digging around in the manuals (learning, notation, snippets), some altagoobingleduckgoing, and making lots of broken lilypond input files.

Comment: Yes! Thank you! This worked perfectly! However, do you mind adding a paragraph explaining how this works? Then I think this answer will be worth an upvote as well!

Answer (score 3):

Something like

```
\new DrumStaff \with {
  instrumentName = #"Güiro "
  shortInstrumentName = #"Guir. "
  \override StaffSymbol.line-count = #1
}
{
  \override NoteHead.style = #'cross
  \override TrillSpanner.bound-details.left.text = ##f
  \override TrillSpanner.bound-details.left.attach-dir = #RIGHT
  \override TrillSpanner.bound-details.right.attach-dir = #LEFT
  \override TrillSpanner.outside-staff-priority = ##f
  \override TrillSpanner.springs-and-rods = #ly:spanner::set-spacing-rods
  \override TrillSpanner.minimum-length = #4
  \override TrillSpanner.Y-offset = #0
  r4 c4\startTrillSpan e8\stopTrillSpan c8 c4 |
}
```

seems to work here.

Comment: This works! I'll be using thrig's method though simply because it's shorter to type `\glissando` every time (instead of `\startTrillSpan\stopTrillSpan`. Thank you very much though! I learnt a lot from this answer, and it followed the original intention I had.